# Kibana discover and LIKE

Tags: kibana, kql

I have rather silly question, how would you search for a occurencies of following string?

```
foothhejbar
foobrndinrhdbar
```

Im basically looking for a way to do search like:

```
"foo"+something+"bar"
```

Is it possible to do such using apostrophe around string?

Bless you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `RLIKE` in KQL
[RLIKE Operater KQL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-like-rlike-operators.html)